# Unity2D Android Touch misbehaving

Tags: android, touch, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to translate an object depending on the touch position of the user.
The problem with it is, when I test it out, the object disappears as soon as I drag my finger on my phone screen. I am not entirely sure what's going on with it?

If somebody can guide me that would be great :)

Thanks

This is the Code:

```
#pragma strict

function Update () {

for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches)
{
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {


    transform.Translate(0, touch.position.y, 0);


}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're moving the object by `touch.position.y`. This isn't a point inworld, it's a point on the touch screen. What you'll want to do is probably `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position).y` which will give you the position inworld for wherever you've touched.

Of course, Translate takes a vector indicating distance, not final destination, so simply sticking  the above in it still won't work as you're intending.

Instead maybe try this:

```
Vector3 EndPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
float speed = 1f;
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, EndPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

which should move the object towards your finger while at the same time keeping its movements smooth looking.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ask this question at Unity's dedicated Questions/Answers site: http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html
There are very few people that come to stackoverflow for Unity specific question, unless they relate to Android/iOS specific features.

As for the cause of your problem, touch.position.y is define in screen space (pixels) where as transform.Translate is expecting world units (meters). You can convert between the two using the Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint() method, then creating a vector out of the camera position and screen world point. With this vector you can then either intersect some geometry in the scene or simply use it as a point in front of the camera.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html